# How do I run Parent and Child Process concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, parallel-processing, subprocess

I have two files. One file shows a part of the image while the other one displays the entire image and a rectangle patch shows the active part of the image being displayed in the other file. I want to run these two files concurrently but the issue is that the other file opens only after the first file is closed. I have tried the following things:

1. os.system("python E:/FYP/software/code/slide_map1.py &")
2. subprocess.call([sys.executable, "E:\FYP\software\code\slide_map1.py", "&"])
3. subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "E:\FYP\software\code\slide_map1.py", "&"])
4. subprocess.call(["python", "E:\FYP\software\code\slide_map1.py"])
   and other similar techniques.
   None of the above-mentioned things have given the desired result. The second file opens only after the first file is closed. I would love to know if there is any other technique that solves my question.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running the same scripts on [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or on multiple CPU cores using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module can be two possible ways of running the two files together.

Also, you might want to look into [concurrency in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html), to get a more indepth understanding of the same to fit it in your code perfectly.

For a quick lookup for future readers here is a list of possible and most commonly used ways -:

- [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module
- [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module
- [concurrent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.html) module

**NOTE:** The ways listed above are not all the possible ways of achieving concurrency, for all possible ways a better resource will be the [official python documentation for the same](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html).